# App stuck on a specific view while running on device

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

i am running an iPhone app successfully on simulator but when i try to run it on device it stuck on a specific view, i have a table view with custom cells having buttons. When i press the buttons after more than four or five times then app works, i also have checked its auto sizing, i don t know why it is not working fine on device, any help please?

```
- (IBAction)didSelectCelebrityNameWithButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
CustomVC *customVC;
if(isFiltered)
    {
    NSLog(@"Celebrity Name : %i", sender.tag-1000);
     customVC = [filteredListResults objectAtIndex:sender.tag-1000];
    }
    else
    {
      customVC = [listResults objectAtIndex:sender.tag-1000];
    }
    if (customVC != nil)
    {
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:UD_FILTER_CELEBRITY_NAME])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:UD_FILTER_CELEBRITY_NAME];
        }
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:customVC.celebrity_name forKey:UD_FILTER_CELEBRITY_NAME];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        RefinedCurrentSearchVC *refinedCurrentSearchVC = [[RefinedCurrentSearchVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"RefinedCurrentSearchVC_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        refinedCurrentSearchVC.isCelebrityFilter = YES;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:refinedCurrentSearchVC animated:YES];
    }
}
```

i am running xcode 4.6.2 and changed its deployment target 4.3 but still problem,

Comment: Try to have break points in your code and see whether this line [self.navigationController pushViewController:refinedCurrentSearchVC animated:YES]; is reached the first time the button is tapped.

Comment: yes it works perfectly on simulator

Comment: Run the app in device and check the break points. To me the code looks fine but I doubt the value set for customVC so that it executes the if condition.

Comment: i  think it is some other kind of issue because if there is an error in code app don t work on simulator, but it works on simulator

Comment: same IOS version in device and simulator?

Comment: Please check the UIControlEvent for Cells Button it suppose to be UIControlEventTouchUpInside ;  Example:                             [CellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in your code,just delete your app from simulator, quit xcode completely and run this app again, hope this will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the reference of your CustomvC, it has to be STRONG, maybe u have it as assign or weak, try it and let me know

Comment: well in my app it was happening this, just when i add the strong reference it worked... dont know why im getting less one??...